# Problema com consulta MySQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

**Estou com o seguinte problema, quando utilizo a clausula WHERE não estou conseguindo utilizar os valores que estão sendo passados por parametro.**

Como retorno tenho a seguinte mensagem:

- PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in*

```
TIPOS DE DADOS NO BANCO

date  tipo -> DATETIME
municipio tipo -> INT
entidade tipo -> INT
```

```
    public function listLicitacoesEntidadesCidades($date, $municipio, $entidade){       

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("
        select 
        tab_licitacoes.id,
        tab_licitacoes.cidade_id,
        tab_licitacoes.entidade_id,
        tab_licitacoes.data_abertura,
        tab_licitacoes.data_cancelamento,
        tab_licitacoes.status,
        tab_licitacoes.modalidade,
        tab_cidades.nome,
        tab_entidades.nome_entidade
            from tab_licitacoes 
            join 
            tab_cidades on (tab_licitacoes.cidade_id = tab_cidades.id)
            join
            tab_entidades on (tab_licitacoes.entidade_id = tab_entidades.id) 
                where 
                tab_licitacoes.status = 'A'
                and
                tab_licitacoes.data_cancelamento >= :date
                and
                tab_licitacoes.cidade_id = :municipio
                and
                tab_licitacoes.entidade_id = :entidade

                ");
        $stmt->bindValue(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':municipio', $municipio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':entidade', $entidade, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $data;

    }
```

Comment: Se você executar esse select direto no banco causa algum erro?

Comment: Passando valores fixos nas 3 variaveis, exemplo :municipio passar 34 retorna exatamente o que preciso

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no que você informou nos comentários, já tentou fazer diferente?

Dessa forma:

```
 public function listLicitacoesEntidadesCidades($date, $municipio, $entidade){       

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("
    select 
    tab_licitacoes.id,
    tab_licitacoes.cidade_id,
    tab_licitacoes.entidade_id,
    tab_licitacoes.data_abertura,
    tab_licitacoes.data_cancelamento,
    tab_licitacoes.status,
    tab_licitacoes.modalidade,
    tab_cidades.nome,
    tab_entidades.nome_entidade
        from tab_licitacoes 
        join 
        tab_cidades on (tab_licitacoes.cidade_id = tab_cidades.id)
        join
        tab_entidades on (tab_licitacoes.entidade_id = tab_entidades.id) 
            where 
            tab_licitacoes.status = 'A'
            and
            tab_licitacoes.data_cancelamento >= ?
            and
            tab_licitacoes.cidade_id = ?
            and
            tab_licitacoes.entidade_id = ?

            ");

    $stmt->execute(array(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date)), $municipio, $entidade));

    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $data;

}
```

> EDITADO

Na assinatura do seu método

```
public function listLicitacoesEntidadesCidades($date, $municipio, $entidade)
```

seu parâmetro **`$date`** é do tipo `DATETIME`?

Quando você vai atribuir a valor ao parâmetro da query

```
$stmt->bindValue(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

você define o parâmetro como *string* em `PDO::PARAM_STR`, então você deve converter **$date** para *string*.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':date', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date)), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Seria isso?

Comment: Eu já havia tentado desta forma, desculpas por não postar. Mas com os outros parâmetros também ocorrem o mesmo problema, é como se não estivesse entendendo os tipos de dados mesmo, tentei forcar a tipagem de dados a todos os parâmetros mesmo assim não funcionou, Mas obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Este erro indica que você está com um número de parâmetros na query diferente daquele que você está preenchendo com suas linhas `bindValue`. Pelo menos no código que você postou isso não está acontecendo. No seu código real, que está executando, não está sobrando ou faltando nada? Está diferente do que você postou aqui?

Comment: Verifica a solução alternativa que postei...

Comment: Já havia tentado, mostra apenas um array vazio, desta forma. contudo há conteúdo na tabela